# How to use watin with WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, watin

Is there any way which would allow me to use watin's functionalities from my web browser control? simply i want to use watin with my web browser control i don't want my application to open a new window ,i need it in my web browser control.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .Net WebBrowser Control you can create WatiN's `IE` object by using following code:

```
var ie = new IE(webBrowser.ActiveXInstance);
```

But if you do that inside your `Form_Load` `ActiveXInstance` will be null. And if you do that for example inside some kind of `button_Click` the application will hang after you use eg. `ie.GoTo`. You need to start new thread and operate there. For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
        var ie = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);
        ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

You need to disable auto start of dialog watcher, because you cannot use built in WatiN dialog watcher. But with a little bit of hacking you can create your own based on original `DialogWatcher` class. Handling popups and creating new web browser controls are also possible.

Comment: If you need to handle dialogs see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455607/watin-and-net-winforms-webbrowser-control-is-dialogwatcher-possible/

Comment: but webBrowser does not have an attribute named "ActiveXInstance". what did I do wrong?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.activexinstance.aspx

Answer (score 2):

( Carbon-copy post for making WatiN's dialog-watcher mechanics work with webbrowser control without much hacking :) )

It is possible to make an embedded webbrowser control to work with WatiN's Dialog-handling mechanism **if you are able to get the window handle of the webbrowser control**, which should be fully possible if you are writing the code of the form that contains it (1)

The reason you need this window handle is exactly because WatiN fails to retrieve it by means of IWebBrowser2.HWND property - this is to be expected. (2)

As a side-note, I have experienced problematic and erratic behavior by IWebBrowser2.HWND property even when dealing with Microsoft's IE - so one more reason to follow the method outlined below to workaround such HWND issues.

Once you get your hands on the window handle of the webbrowser control you can simply make a proxy class that wraps around the IWebBrowser2 interface of the embedded web-browser (with the exception of HWND) so as to workaround the problem. Putting it all together you can now write:

```
 Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = true;
 new IE(new ProxyForIWebBrowser2InterfaceToWorkaroundHWNDBugs((IWebBrowser2) webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance, webBrowser1.Handle), true);
```

Hope this helps. Oh, and here's the proxy class you'll need:

```
 using System;
 using SHDocVw;

 namespace WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer
 {
public class ProxyForIWebBrowser2InterfaceToWorkaroundHWNDBugs : IWebBrowser2
{
    #region Implementation of IWebBrowser
    private readonly int _ExplicitHwndForIWebBrowser2;
    private readonly IWebBrowser2 _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2;
    public ProxyForIWebBrowser2InterfaceToWorkaroundHWNDBugs(IWebBrowser2 embeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2, IntPtr explicitHwnd)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2 = embeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2;
        _ExplicitHwndForIWebBrowser2 = (int)explicitHwnd;
    }

    void IWebBrowser.GoBack()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoBack();
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.GoForward()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoForward();
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.GoHome()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoHome();
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.GoSearch()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoSearch();
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.Navigate(string URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Navigate(URL, ref Flags, ref TargetFrameName, ref PostData, ref Headers);
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.Refresh()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Refresh();
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.Refresh2(ref object Level)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Refresh2(ref Level);
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.Stop()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Stop();
    }

    object IWebBrowser2.Application
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Application; }
    }

    object IWebBrowser2.Parent
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Parent; }
    }

    object IWebBrowser2.Container
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Container; }
    }

    object IWebBrowser2.Document
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Document; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser2.TopLevelContainer
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.TopLevelContainer; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.Type
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Type; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser2.Left
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Left; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Left = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser2.Top
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Top; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Top = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser2.Width
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Width; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Width = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser2.Height
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Height; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Height = value; }
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.Quit()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Quit();
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.ClientToWindow(ref int pcx, ref int pcy)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ClientToWindow(ref pcx, ref pcy);
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.PutProperty(string Property, object vtValue)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.PutProperty(Property, vtValue);
    }

    object IWebBrowser2.GetProperty(string Property)
    {
        return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GetProperty(Property);
    }

    public void Navigate2(ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Navigate2(ref URL, ref Flags, ref TargetFrameName, ref PostData, ref Headers);
    }

    public OLECMDF QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID cmdID)
    {
        return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.QueryStatusWB(cmdID);
    }

    public void ExecWB(OLECMDID cmdID, OLECMDEXECOPT cmdexecopt, ref object pvaIn, ref object pvaOut)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ExecWB(cmdID, cmdexecopt, ref pvaIn, ref pvaOut);
    }

    public void ShowBrowserBar(ref object pvaClsid, ref object pvarShow, ref object pvarSize)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ShowBrowserBar(ref pvaClsid, ref pvarShow, ref pvarSize);
    }

    void IWebBrowser2.GoBack()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoBack();
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.GoForward()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoForward();
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.GoHome()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoHome();
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.GoSearch()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoSearch();
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.Navigate(string URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Navigate(URL, ref Flags, ref TargetFrameName, ref PostData, ref Headers);
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.Refresh()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Refresh();
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.Refresh2(ref object Level)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Refresh2(ref Level);
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.Stop()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Stop();
    }

    object IWebBrowserApp.Application
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Application; }
    }

    object IWebBrowserApp.Parent
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Parent; }
    }

    object IWebBrowserApp.Container
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Container; }
    }

    object IWebBrowserApp.Document
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Document; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowserApp.TopLevelContainer
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.TopLevelContainer; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.Type
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Type; }
    }

    int IWebBrowserApp.Left
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Left; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Left = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowserApp.Top
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Top; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Top = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowserApp.Width
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Width; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Width = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowserApp.Height
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Height; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Height = value; }
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.Quit()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Quit();
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.ClientToWindow(ref int pcx, ref int pcy)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ClientToWindow(ref pcx, ref pcy);
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.PutProperty(string Property, object vtValue)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.PutProperty(Property, vtValue);
    }

    object IWebBrowserApp.GetProperty(string Property)
    {
        return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GetProperty(Property);
    }

    void IWebBrowserApp.GoBack()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoBack();
    }

    void IWebBrowser.GoForward()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoForward();
    }

    void IWebBrowser.GoHome()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoHome();
    }

    void IWebBrowser.GoSearch()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.GoSearch();
    }

    void IWebBrowser.Navigate(string URL, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, ref object Headers)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Navigate(URL, ref Flags, ref TargetFrameName, ref PostData, ref Headers);
    }

    void IWebBrowser.Refresh()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Refresh();
    }

    void IWebBrowser.Refresh2(ref object Level)
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Refresh2(ref Level);
    }

    void IWebBrowser.Stop()
    {
        _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Stop();
    }

    object IWebBrowser.Application
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Application; }
    }

    object IWebBrowser.Parent
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Parent; }
    }

    object IWebBrowser.Container
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Container; }
    }

    object IWebBrowser.Document
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Document; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser.TopLevelContainer
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.TopLevelContainer; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser.Type
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Type; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser.Left
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Left; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Left = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser.Top
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Top; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Top = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser.Width
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Width; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Width = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser.Height
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Height; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Height = value; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser.LocationName
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.LocationName; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.LocationURL
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.LocationURL; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser2.Busy
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Busy; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.Name
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Name; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser2.HWND
    {
        get { return _ExplicitHwndForIWebBrowser2; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.FullName
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.FullName; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.Path
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Path; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser2.Visible
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Visible; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Visible = value; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser2.StatusBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusBar = value; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.StatusText
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusText; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusText = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowser2.ToolBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ToolBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ToolBar = value; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser2.MenuBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.MenuBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.MenuBar = value; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser2.FullScreen
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.FullScreen; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.FullScreen = value; }
    }

    public tagREADYSTATE ReadyState
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ReadyState; }
    }

    public bool Offline
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Offline; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Offline = value; }
    }

    public bool Silent
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Silent; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Silent = value; }
    }

    public bool RegisterAsBrowser
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.RegisterAsBrowser; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.RegisterAsBrowser = value; }
    }

    public bool RegisterAsDropTarget
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.RegisterAsDropTarget; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.RegisterAsDropTarget = value; }
    }

    public bool TheaterMode
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.TheaterMode; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.TheaterMode = value; }
    }

    public bool AddressBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.AddressBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.AddressBar = value; }
    }

    public bool Resizable
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Resizable; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Resizable = value; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser2.LocationName
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.LocationName; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.LocationURL
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.LocationURL; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowserApp.Busy
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Busy; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.Name
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Name; }
    }

    int IWebBrowserApp.HWND
    {
        get { return _ExplicitHwndForIWebBrowser2; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.FullName
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.FullName; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.Path
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Path; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowserApp.Visible
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Visible; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Visible = value; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowserApp.StatusBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusBar = value; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.StatusText
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusText; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.StatusText = value; }
    }

    int IWebBrowserApp.ToolBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ToolBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.ToolBar = value; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowserApp.MenuBar
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.MenuBar; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.MenuBar = value; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowserApp.FullScreen
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.FullScreen; }
        set { _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.FullScreen = value; }
    }

    string IWebBrowserApp.LocationName
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.LocationName; }
    }

    string IWebBrowser.LocationURL
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.LocationURL; }
    }

    bool IWebBrowser.Busy
    {
        get { return _EmbeddedWebBrowserAsIWebBrowser2.Busy; }
    }

    #endregion
       }
   }
```

1: Even if you don't you have source-code access to such a form because, say, webbrowser control is in a 3rd party app that you have no access to, you can write a small utility function to scan all windows till you stumble upon the 3rd-party app that contains the webbrowser control you are after. You can have a look in WatiN's source code, inside ShellWindows2.CollectInternetExplorerInstances() to get an idea on how you can implement such a scan-function.

2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244310

Answer (score 0):

Create your IE object using a WebBrowser2 interface from your web browser control, something like:

```
var CurrentBrowser = new IE(WebBrowser2);
```

One important point is to be sure to set `AutoStartDialogWatcher` to false in WatiN settings. Since you are not implementing IE anymore, you are responsible for all dialogs.