# Attaching to WebBrowser with WatiN throws Exception HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, watin

I'm using WatiN to attach to a WebBrowser control. The following code throws "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." in the IE constructor.

```
using (IE ie = new IE(browser.ActiveXInstance))
{
    ie.GoTo(uri);
}
```

Solution!

```
Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
using (IE ie = new IE(browser.ActiveXInstance))
{
    ie.GoTo(uri);
}
```

See [How to use watin with WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755747/how-to-use-watin-with-webbrowser-control) for further information about a replacement dialog watcher.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at this Stack Overflow thing. I saw the "[x] answer your own question" just after I pressed submit. Sorry.

```
Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
using (IE ie = new IE(browser.ActiveXInstance))
{
    ie.GoTo(uri);
}
```

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question, but you may want to edit your question so it looks as a *question*, i.e., remove the answer from there and keep it here.